# Django newbie error: NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseClient must provide a runshell() method

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I'm newbie in django&co world... these last few days it was working the dbshell but I don't really know what I touched because it is producing it to crash... I would be greatfull for any clue. Attaching the error.
I'm trying to make a rest API with django, mongodb connected by djongo.

```
(DjangoProject) C:\Users\Skootik\alchemyml_services>python manage.py dbshell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Skootik\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Skootik\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Skootik\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Skootik\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Skootik\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\dbshell.py", line 22, in handle
    connection.client.runshell()
  File "C:\Users\Skootik\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\client.py", line 12, in runshell
    raise NotImplementedError('subclasses of BaseDatabaseClient must provide a runshell() method')
NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseClient must provide a runshell() method
```

Comment: Did you configure a database engine in your Django project settings yet? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#dbshell

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did as Djongo specifies (https://github.com/nesdis/djongo): DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'dbAmlApi',
    }
}, and it worked... but for sure I did smth that messed up the things.

Comment: Ok, as I'm working on I'll give more details... I overrided the User class (needed email to be unique, and also added some more fields). In settings added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'services.User'`. Also I tried to added to the Django Admin: `admin.site.register(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, CustomUserAdmin)` ... I missing smth and I don't know what... Thanks in advance